# P/Invoke Fortran Dll causing unhandled exception when using intrinsic functions

Tags: c#, pinvoke, fortran

Fortran Code

```
FUNCTION ComputeSquareRoot(inputValue) 
IMPLICIT NONE
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'ComputeSquareRoot' :: ComputeSquareRoot
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: ComputeSquareRoot
REAL*8 :: inputValue   
REAL*8 :: ComputeSquareRoot
    ComputeSquareRoot = SQRT(inputValue)
RETURN 
END FUNCTION
```

C# Code

```
    [DllImport("TestingFortranDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern double ComputeSquareRoot(ref double inputValue);

    /// <summary>
    /// Wrapper method for ComputeSquareRoot.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static double CallingComputeSquareRoot()
    {
        var inputValue = 100.0;

        return ComputeSquareRoot(ref inputValue);
    }
```

Exception

Unhandled exception has occurred in a component in your application....

Unable to load DLL "TestingFortranDll.dll": The specific module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:0x8007007E)

This exception occurs only when I try to use implict functions like SQRT.

Comment: how do you create your fortran dll? which compiler?

Comment: Compiled with Intel Fortran compiler.
http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-composer-xe/

Comment: For what its worth, these days you are far better off using F2003's C interoperability feature to link languages together, rather than relying on the vagaries of particular compilers/compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the dll is missing some of its dependencies. Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find which dlls are missing

There is some information [here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabWindows-CVI/I-can-t-run-my-DLLs-without-having-Intel-Fortran-Composer-in-the/td-p/1451790) about finding the Fortran redistributable files. You will need to supply them with your dll. For test, just copy them to the same directory and see whether it helps.

Comment: Strange thing is if I use SQRT(4.0) inside Fortran code and PInvoke it gives me 2.0 as result.

Comment: You mean it only fails when you use the argument? What if you remove `ref` from the signature (I don't know much about the fortran, but the argument seems to be sent by value). You can get the exact signature of the method by calling `dumpbin /exports testingfortrandll.dll` from VS command line.

Comment: No the arguments are by reference. Otherwise I agree with the need for the Fortran redistributable library.

Comment: I found those redist *.dlls and *.msm file but I do not know what to do with them.

Comment: The sqrt(4.0) is computed at compile-time as 2.0, that's why he doesn't need the library.

Comment: @thanda, just put these dlls with your dll and see if it works

Comment: Removing `ref` does not change anything.

Comment: see Vladimir's answer. It seems that the compiler treats all parameters as by ref, so you signature is fine.